# Debug Assertion Failed in for

Tags: c++

I got an error on second if

Making the exactly same if outside of for seems to work just fine, it returns the value from priority function, but when I try to do it in for it said that I'm trying to pass an invalid parameter to a function which considers it to be fatal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int priority(char c);

int main()
{
stack<char>Operator;
string input;
string output;
getline(cin, input);
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '(' || input[i] == ')' || input[i] == '+' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == '*' || input[i] == '/')
        Operator.push(input[i]);
    else
        output.push_back(input[i]);
    if (priority(Operator.top()) == 3)
    {
        int aux = Operator.top();
        Operator.pop();
        while (priority(Operator.top() == 4))
        {
            output.push_back((char)Operator.top());
            Operator.pop();
        }
        Operator.push(aux);
    }
    if (priority(Operator.top() == 2))
    {
        Operator.pop();
        while (priority(Operator.top()) != 1)
        {
            output.push_back(Operator.top());
            Operator.pop();
        }
        Operator.pop();
    }
}
cout << output;
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

int priority(char c)
{
if (c == '(')
    return 1;
if (c == ')')
    return 2;
if (c == '+' || c == '-')
    return 3;
if (c == '*' || c == '/')
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be way too sure about the size of `Operator` at each step. Also note that those two `if`s can be both true in one iteration - is that what you want? Well, your loops just do not know when to stop... You cannot do `Operator.top()` when `Operator.empty()`. One short-cirtuiting `&&` should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Operator.top()` is being called on every symbol in the input string. That would probably work in case your string starts with a `'('` symbol or with a unary plus, but what would happen in case of `"2*2"`?

As a perfect solution you should redesign your code to make it a finit automaton. As a simple ad hoc fix you should check if the current symbol is an operation or digit and don't call the Operator.top() in the latter case:

```
if (isdigit(input[i])) {
    output.push_back(input[i]);
}
else {
    Operator.push(input[i]);
    if (priority(Operator.top()) == 3) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i fixed it,i just stopped using string and used char instead and it worked , idk why tho, i also used your isdigit but i also add isalpha aswell bcs the output should be smth like this: input: (a*(b-c)+d/(e+f*h)-i)  output: abc-*drfh*+/i-+